# Not seeing table updates in Visual Studio for Azure Analysis Services model

Tags: visual-studio, azure-analysis-services

I have a model in Azure Analysis Services I'm maintaining through Visual Studio.

The user added some fields to the source table in Snowflake, and I need to pull them into the model.

I right-click on the table and select Table Properties, then go into the Power Query Editor.

I refresh the preview, the new columns appear.

I go to Columns->Choose Columns, the new columns are there and already selected since (Select All Columns) was originally checked.  I click OK, then Home->Close & Update.

The SQL statement has changed, I see the new columns listed at the end.  I click OK.

Nothing happens.  The new columns don't appear in the drop-down in the Tabular Model Explorer, and the model doesn't indicate anything changed.

Obviously I'm missing a step here, would appreciate any guidance folks can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue -- apparently VS didn't like the alias name the editor was adding to the query.  When I simplified the alias to a single word, the update took no problem.